# Ursina.build can't find modules?

Tags: python, numpy, panda3d, ursina

I was reading [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71184949/i-have-problem-with-ursina-when-it-get-compiled-to-exe), when it said I was supposed to use the command `python -m ursina.build` to compile my project. When I launched the .bat file I got this error

```
package_folder: C:\Users\sbahr\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\MeshGame\build\python\lib\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: src
screen resolution: (1920, 1080)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sbahr\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\MeshGame\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mesh import ChunkManager
  File "C:\Users\sbahr\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\MeshGame\mesh.py", line 19, in <module>
    from noise import generateSaveNoise
  File "C:\Users\sbahr\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\MeshGame\noise.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I ran `pip install numpy` and it said numpy was already installed.

Comment: You seem to be running a Python version that's inside your MeshGame folder. The `pip` command you ran likely installed numpy to the system wide location.

Answer (score 2):

This used to be automatic, but broke in a newer version of Python. Therefore you'll have to provide a list of extra modules to copy, if you're using any.
From ursina's documentation (https://www.ursinaengine.org/building.html):

> Make sure to include any extra modules with `--include_modules PIL,numpy` for example.

Comment: For some reason it needed JSON even though I never used it in my project, when I did `--include_modules JSON` it told me I didn't have json installed, I double checked it was installed.